# Cloudant query error: missing search index when trying to sort

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I've followed the [Cloudant tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/tutorials/create_query.html#creating-a-cloudant-query) from IBM on how to run a query to retrieve a selection of documents, and sort these based on a field's value. The instructions start about 2/3rd way down the page at "Running a query with two fields".

I'm getting an error which I can't find a solution for.

> Unknown Error: mango_idx :: {no_usable_index,missing_sort_index}

The query is:

```
{
"selector": {
  "lastname": "Brown",
  "location": "New York City, NY"
},
"fields": [
  "firstname",
  "lastname",
  "location"
],
"sort": [
  {
    "lastname": "asc"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "asc"
  }
]
}
```

I have a query index added to the design documents, as given:

```
{
"index": {
  "fields": [
    "lastname",  
    "location",
    "age"
  ]
},
"name": "query-index",
"type": "json"
}
```

The documents themselves are variants of:

```
{
"firstname": "John",
"lastname": "Brown",
"age": 21,
"location": "New York City, NY",
"_id": "doc2"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Did something change in the Cloudant syntax that the tutorial wasn't updated on?

I'm aware of ["Unknown Error: mango_idx :: {no_usable_index,missing_sort_index}"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584988/unknown-error-mango-idx-no-usable-index-missing-sort-index) of which the suggested answers don't help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unknown Error: mango\_idx :: {no\_usable\_index,missing\_sort\_index}"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584988/unknown-error-mango-idx-no-usable-index-missing-sort-index)

Comment: I have looked at the suggested answers there, which do not help me, I have followed your (IBM) tutorial to the letter which resulted in this problem. I have also reported this issue on the documentation's github repository: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix-Docs/Cloudant/issues/2

Comment: @Joeri the tutorial will be corrected. You should get an official answer here on SO soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like this is an issue with that tutorial. There is no index to support sorting by lastname and firstname. You can create another index like this:

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [
      "lastname",
      "firstname"
    ]
  },
  "type": "json"
}
```

Alternatively you could sort only by lastname (take out firstname). This will be supported by the original index. Query would look like this:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "lastname": "Brown",
    "location": "New York City, NY"
  },
  "fields": [
    "firstname",
    "lastname",
    "location"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "lastname": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @markwatsonatx! I will update my github issue about the tutorial with your solution. https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix-Docs/Cloudant/issues/2#issuecomment-327289797