# How to sort on multiple fields individually using a single index

Tags: node.js, couchdb, nano

I am trying to declare multiple fields in a single index like below and trying to sort on the single field only. is it possible?

Is there any way by which using a single combine fields index I can sort on individual fields dynamically.

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": ["name","createdDate","updatedDate"]
    },
    "name" : "multi-filter",
    "ddoc" : "MultiFilter"
    "type" : "json"
}
```

after that, I can apply sort on the same sequence and list like

```
{
    "selector": {"name": "Robert De Niro"},
    "sort": [{"name": "asc"}, {"createdDate": "asc"},{"updatedDate": "asc"}]
}
```

BUT if I change the sequence or want to use a filter/sort on a single field like

```
{
    "selector": {"name": "Robert De Niro"},
    "sort": [{"name": "asc"}]
}
```

it gives an error saying, my motive is to use the single index, but sort individual fields. It looks like it is a limitation of couch DB and I need to create three separate indexes for the same to make it work, still hoping for the best option

```
{"error":"no_usable_index","reason":"No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields."}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer here: ["Unknown Error: mango_idx :: {no_usable_index,missing_sort_index}"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584988/unknown-error-mango-idx-no-usable-index-missing-sort-index?noredirect=1&lq=1)

you could define an index only with the good field, eg:

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": ["name"]
    },
    "name" : "name_sort",
    "type" : "json"
}
```