# CouchDB/Cloudant query view by key that is array?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

```
alice.view('characters', 'soldiers', {
  'keys': ['Hearts', 'Clubs']
}, function(err, body) {
  if (!err) {
    body.rows.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.value);
    });
  }
});
```

Does this filter on `key: "Heart"` or `key: "Clubs"` or the exact match `key: ["Hearts", "Clubs"]`? I wish to do the latter where my keys are arrays with 2 items.

Also if I JUST inserted into the db, can I expect this view to immediately be up to date when I run that code?

Answer (score 1):

the `view()` function above will filter on key: "Heart" or key: "Clubs".
instead, you may want to try using the `startkey` and `endkey`:

```
*DB_NAME*/_design/characters/_view/soldiers?startkey=["Hearts", "Clubs"]&endkey=["Hearts", "Clubs"]&inclusive_end=true
```

something, like this:

```
alice.view('characters', 'soldiers', {
  'startkey': ['Hearts', 'Clubs'],
  'endkey': ['Hearts', 'Clubs'],
  'inclusive_end': true
}, function(err, body) {
  if (!err) {
    body.rows.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.value);
    });
  }
})
```

reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42398481

Comment: Do you know if just `key: ['Hearts', 'Clubs']` works? Why the `startKey` and `endKey`?